# I would like to flag a duplicate but there is no upvote / accepted answer. In this case, why would a duplicate answer be removed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Rules and rules, and they are made to allow the community to work properly and to help each other. Yet, sometimes this does not happen.

I've found the following two questions, where I wanted to post two identical answers:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983776/)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503668/)

Now, I know that doing this is wrong. One should flag one of the two questions as a duplicate, and answer only the main one.

But how can you do that, if there are no upvotes / accepted answers?

**So I actually did it and I've posted the same answer twice**

I am writing here because something else happened:

[image: This]

The most frustrating part? I could not comment to explain the situation. Why would you cancel the answer when it is the correct one? At least, **do your work as moderator and actually mark the duplicate!**

I supposed that the website checks if you post the same content twice, so I've just posted a slightly different answer, adding a note for the moderators:

[image]

And the adventure goes on! Someone recently edited my question, bringing us to this kind of situation:

[image]

Now, it could be solved with a simple upvote-then-flag_as_duplicate, but I would be happy if we could avoid such a deadlock in the future. How can this be done?

Maybe I just followed the wrong step from the beginning, and all of this is my fault

Comment: @yivi so not even the moderator can overcome that upvote limitation? It doesn't really make sense. At least, anyone (including a moderator) can upvote - then flag. I cannot, as there are my answers

Comment: Anyone can upvote, if they know enough about the technology stack to ascertain the post quality, think the post if worth an upvote, wants to spend a vote, and has votes available. Moderators are not necessarily experts in the subject matter of the post they moderate. You need to wait until the votes come naturally.

Comment: @yivi Moderators are not subject to the stupid "must have an upvoted answer in order to close as duplicate" limitation.

Comment: @yivi so we don't upvote, but we remove legit answer or we edit them as we like

Comment: Removing noise from a  post does not require subject matter expertise. Removing duplicate content, either. Upvoting usually does, though.

Comment: @yivi **Removing duplicate content either**. You are right, I didn't reflect before commenting. Still, I cannot remove that bad feeling "It should not work in this way"

Comment: Thanks for writing this Meta question. I was contemplating adding an upvote to one of your answers, in order to be able to start a duplicate closure process. However you asked for an upvote, and I tend not to upvote when people ask for upvotes; I was worried also that the upvote would effectively reward some post vandalism that we discourage here. So I was a bit conflicted, though I probably would have acquiesced in the end - I bookmarked the page for later consideration.

Comment: The correct solution to this problem is to answer one of the questions, receive a single upvote, and then flag the duplicate question.  What you don't do is copy and paste the exact same answer, to multiple questions, I cannot think of a single reason anyone would do that.

Comment: @SecurityHound The lack of patience is a totally reasonable answer :P

Comment: @halfer I can totally understand

Comment: @Federico - You knew exactly what you were doing.  You knew from your own description you knew it was a bad idea.  You knew it wasn’t what you were supposed to do.  Why do I suspect that?  You wanted to close the question as a duplicate which shows you knew what the correct action actually was

Comment: @SecurityHound Ehi, that is not wrong! But what crossed my mind is "there are two ways to close properly a question on SA: close it for reasons (ex: it is a duplicate) or answering it. Case closed"

Comment: @FedericoDorato - When you answer a question it is not closed.  It remains open.  You also have to keep in mind, you resubmitted an answer, that was deleted a third time.  Instead of raising the issue in a chatroom or even meta before you submitted the answer a second time, you submitted it a second and third time and this situation could have been avoided.

Comment: @SecurityHound The comment was probably the most "let's stick to the rules" action, and I still don't really like the idea a lot. I've never used the chatroom, and probably I should start to. I don't really get what "third time" you are talking about tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overriding guideline in this case is that we don't allow meta-material in posts. There is probably some wiggle-room for community discussion here, but to my mind this includes:

- Complaints about how people have voted
- Advice or pleading about how people should or should not vote in the future
- Commentary on how the writer themselves will vote or normally votes
- Instructions on how to use the platform (e.g. that readers should comment if something is not clear, or that they should explain their downvotes)
- Notes to moderators, gold-badge holders, close/reopen voters, etc.
- Commentary about quality standards on Stack Overflow (e.g. that it is too lax, or that it is not welcoming of beginners, etc).

When people answer questions here, we want the material to be succinct and to address the question directly. We trim out all of the above, plus chatty material, supplementary questions, and invitations for discussion in the comments. That is how we remain focussed on the Q&A format here, and I think there is some consensus that this approach works fairly well.

Where people post duplicate answers (or where their answers will be exact duplicates after the meta-material is excised) we generally delete the duplicates. This is because any improvements made to one really ought to be made to the others, but most times, the editor won't know the others exist, and so the answers will slowly diverge over time. This increases the burden of work on volunteers.

To detect duplicates, often what happens is that a curator runs a search and notices two or more identical-looking results, and where they discover they are near or exact copies, they will generally add a comment to each one, containing links to all copies. Then, one of the duplicates will be flagged for a moderator, who will investigate and delete as they feel appropriate. In general mods will try to delete copies based on a good compromise between not hurting an answerer by docking their earned points, while also aiming for the best content outcome for future readers.

So, if you encounter this situation again, try to cast a close vote in the first instance. If the system does not allow it, as was the case here, then just add a comment link from the purported duplicate to your answer, and people who have a similar problem can just follow the link.

Comment: I will follow this suggestion if I were to end up again in this situation. I am surprised that you did not propose something like "if you question both are lacking upvote/accepted answer, there should be the possibility to flag the duplicate and to have a moderator handling it"

Comment: @FedericoDorato: I don't have any information as to whether mods would welcome those flags, and personally speaking I would not flag in this case (as this is generally meant to be a case that the community can handle without a moderator). However, you can always try it, and the worse that will happen is that the flag would be declined.

Comment: Of course, it may be worth searching this Meta site to see if anyone has asked a question about getting rid of the restriction that questions can only be flagged as duplicates if there is an upvoted answer. Cody indicates in the comments that he doesn't like that rule, and mods are not subject to it, so I suspect there will be a proportion of the community that would be open to it. If the topic has never been raised before (doubtful but possible) then you can always create a new feature-suggestion topic on it.